# Air, water, and ...?

Tags: science-fiction, alternate-worlds, names

Suppose you have a planet with *two* different, immiscible, ocean-forming liquids. You start out immersed in gaseous air, and you can walk down the sea shore where there's a clear interface with liquid. But then, if you dive/wade down into the water, after a while you run into *another* "sea shore", where there's a clear interface with a much denser liquid- it refracts light, you can float on it, boats that are too heavy to float on the first surface can sink down and float on the second surface, sailing underwater.

What would you call the two different levels of ocean? "Water" and *something*? *Something* and "water"? Or some other names entirely?

Note that I'm presuming your civilization has developed having always been aware that there are three levels of air/liquid/other-liquid from time immemorial, not that this second layer is newly discovered at some point.

Comment: I'd be tempted to break out some pseudo-Latin... if it were Earth, and this second layer were discovered at some point that scientists were using Latin for scientific terms.  If it's discovered "from time immemorial" I'd think you'd have some basic word for it - something that we likely don't have.

Comment: @Ghotir Perhaps the `Tethean` after [Tethyus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethys_(mythology)), in comparison to the `Ocean` after `Oceaneus`?

Comment: This is really a list question.  There is no answer.  Lingusitics would let you know that absolutely any answer is valid.  It really would come down to how the discoverer of this layer felt at the time, and the entire body of language that lead up to this point.   Personally, I'd go for "under-water"

Comment: Depending on how deep it is, it would have to be pretty newly discovered. Unless your inhabitants are water breathers. not sure there is any particular value to floating a boat on a denser liquid below the ocean. Sailing wouldn't happen. There are actually places you can see the simple thermocline, between water of different densities, and fine sand will sit on the interface

Comment: You could look up the names for the different levels of the ocean. Name your 'different' ocean after/along similar lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you ever considered calling it a [seep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_seep), or seep ocean?

Seeps are places where water, or a very different type of water, gathers or percolates up to form a pool. Cold Seeps, as in the link above, are these underwater pools in the deep ocean. Obviously, your other-ocean is on a much larger scale, but I don't think this is entirely unrealistic. Here is a picture of a cold seep community:

[image: A underwater pool!]

The black, glassy portion of the picture is actually and underwater pool. These communities of animals are really neat because they do not require heat nor sunlight, just the "briny goodness" of the seep.

Comment: I think simply "The Seep" would be a cool and descriptive name.

Comment: I like that it rhymes with "The Deep", which as long been a poetic name for the deepest waters, from which the foundations of the earth spring up.

Comment: I love this answer. Here is a picture that shows a guy diving in a seep, for dramatic effect: https://circacity.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/underwaterlake3.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Alternate words for water:

- Aqua
- Pani

Totally different liquids:

- Oil (note: oil is lighter than water so you would have an ocean of oil between the air and water layer)
- Slime
- Gel

As for some various terms to help describe the two ocean levels:

- Oceana
- Oceaneus
- Over-Ocean
- Under-Ocean
- Subocean
- Superocean
- Atlanta/Atlantic/Atlantis

Also, it is not unreasonable to call them both oceans and rely on names to separate them.  Like your planet's Pacific Ocean is actually located below its Atlantic Ocean.  On Earth we distinguish between fresh water and salt water so it is not unreasonable to call both liquids water and add an extra word that provides their distinguishing characteristic.

Answer (score 1):

I think the name referring to the lowest level could depend on benefits/drawbacks.

Possible drawbacks include:

- More predators
- Harder to move around
- Inability to sustain (cannot breathe)
- Harder to see

Possible advantages could include:

- Less predators
- Easier to escape predators (Maybe there are creatures that roam freely in the water, but cannot roam freely in the below water)
- Easier to see (Not as blinding)

If there are more benefits, the area could be called something with a positive connotation like Sanctuary Zone, if there are more drawbacks it could be called the Dark Deep.

Edit:

If you are looking for a more scientific style name, perhaps call it **The Precipitate**, as in the part that is deposited from a chemical solution.